# How do I authorize $50 but then capture $40?

Tags: ios, go, stripe-payments

I start with `SetupIntentParams`:

```
  piparams := &stripe.SetupIntentParams{
    Customer:           stripe.String(cID),
    PaymentMethodTypes: stripe.StringSlice([]string{"card"}),
  }
  si, _ := setupintent.New(piparams)
```

This works an I'm able to send JSON to ios with:

```
  send["setup_intent"] = si.ID
  send["client_secret"] = si.ClientSecret
  send["ephemeral_key"] = ek.Secret
  send["customer_id"] = cID
  send["publishable_key"] = PK
```

ios uses this to add a new payment method to the customer's account.

Then ios sends go the new payment_method_id and go uses it to make a `PaymentIntent`:

```
  piparams := &stripe.PaymentIntentParams{
    Amount:             stripe.Int64(5000),
    Currency:           stripe.String(string(stripe.CurrencyUSD)),
    Customer:           stripe.String(cID),
    PaymentMethod:      stripe.String(pmid),
    Confirm:            stripe.Bool(false),
    SetupFutureUsage:   stripe.String("off_session"),
    ConfirmationMethod: stripe.String(string(stripe.PaymentIntentConfirmationMethodAutomatic)),
  }
  pi, _ := paymentintent.New(piparams)
```

I'm careful to set `SetupFutureUsage` to `off_session` and I successfully make the payment intent. I don't want to capture the final amount yet. Some time needs to go by so I know what to charge the user and then I want to call:

```
  p, _ := paymentintent.Get(pi, nil)
  _, err = paymentintent.Capture(p.ID, &stripe.PaymentIntentCaptureParams{
    AmountToCapture: stripe.Int64(4000),
  })
```

But I get one of these errors:

```
This PaymentIntent could not be captured because it has a status of requires_confirmation.
```

or

```
"This PaymentIntent could not be captured because it has already been captured.
```

or

```
This PaymentIntent could not be captured because it has a status of requires_action.
```

Depending on how I set

```
    Confirm:            stripe.Bool(false),
    ConfirmationMethod: stripe.String(string(stripe.PaymentIntentConfirmationMethodAutomatic)),
```

And if ios does a confirm or not. What am I missing? Why can't I get this into a state where ios leaves the PaymentIntent all confirmed and ready for go to Capture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of these errors are for [different states](https://docs.stripe.com/payments/paymentintents/lifecycle#intent-statuses) of the Payment Intent.  `requires_confirmaion` means the Intent needs to be confirmed,  If you do not need to interact with the customer you should pass `Comfirm: stripe.Bool(true)`.

`requires_action` means something, likely 3DS authentication, is required to complete the payment.

`already_captured` means you've already done it and can't do it again.

Your app needs to inspect the resulting Payment Intent after creation to determine what the [status](https://docs.stripe.com/payments/paymentintents/lifecycle#intent-statuses) is.  Your app will need to take different actions depending on what the current state of your Payment Intent is and you will need to program that logic on your end.

- For `requires_confirmation`, you should use the [Payment Sheet](https://docs.stripe.com/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=ios&ui=payment-sheet) to confirm the payment
- For `requires_action`, you should also use the [Payment Sheet](https://docs.stripe.com/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=ios&ui=payment-sheet) since that will automatically trigger the [authentication required](https://docs.stripe.com/payments/3d-secure/authentication-flow?platform=ios)

Comment: working with!  Confirm:            stripe.Bool(false),
    SetupFutureUsage:   stripe.String("off_session"),
    ConfirmationMethod: stripe.String(string(stripe.PaymentIntentConfirmationMethodAutomatic)),
    CaptureMethod:      stripe.String(string(stripe.PaymentIntentCaptureMethodManual)),